# How to provide this Firestore Security Rule

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to write some security rules to my firestore.
There is 2 section in my db, one of them is guest info and other one is passwords.

All the things about guest info works at my NextJS code.

But i am updating my passwords daily with another javascript file.

Here is  the security rule of my db currently

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

if i keep the rules like this i am not able to update my passwords with my other javascript file because i can not send authed request to firestore. How can i solve my problem?

Comment: What does the other JS file look like? Does it run in a browser too or some server?

Comment: @Dharmaraj sorry i forgot to mention, it is on server

Answer (score 1):

If the other JS file runs on a server, you can use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) instead that bypasses any security rules. Then you don't have to authenticate like in Client SDKs but just ensure that the script can be called by authorized users only.